# SQL 2005 to 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I am in the midst of upgrading to SQL Server 2012 from 2005 and came across a syntax error that I need help with. The syntax error is actually in a database that was built in 2000 so the compatibility issue cannot be fixed in the settings.

```
    Select      PPB.*,      

    SUBSTRING(STUFF((select license_id as k   --*
    FROM LMACatscan..license AS L 
          WHERE L.archived = 0 
                AND ((L.ppb_id IN (SELECT ppb_id FROM LMACatscan..ppb WHERE ppb_id = PPB.ppb_id)) 
                OR (L.ppb_id_2 IN (SELECT ppb_id FROM LMACatscan..ppb WHERE ppb_id = PPB.ppb_id)))
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,''),2,999999)    
                FROM   LMACatscan..ppb AS PPB    
                WHERE  state_code > ''
```

The results from 2005 are: [image]
From 20012 you can see the column with no name has that same value for all rows and this is where the problem is: [image]As always, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem lies here:

```
((L.ppb_id IN (SELECT ppb_id FROM LMACatscan..ppb WHERE ppb_id = PPB.ppb_id)) 
OR (L.ppb_id_2 IN (SELECT ppb_id FROM LMACatscan..ppb WHERE ppb_id = PPB.ppb_id)))
```

What it's doing is selecting everything from the license_id column where either the ppb_id or ppb_id_2 is in the PPB table's ppb_id column. Which means you're concatenating every match for every row (even if the ppb_id doesn't exist in the license table, it will still show this on that line)

This should fix it:

```
SELECT PPB.*,
    SUBSTRING(STUFF((SELECT license_id k
        FROM LMACatscan..license L
        WHERE (L.ppb_id = PPB.ppb_id
        OR L.ppb_id_2 = PPB.ppb_id)
        AND L.Archived = 0
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,''),2,999999)
FROM LMACatscan..ppb PPB
WHERE state_code > ''
```

By the way, the stuff statement is literally doing nothing. You can just remove it if you like.

```
SELECT PPB.*,
    SUBSTRING((SELECT license_id k
        FROM license L
        WHERE (L.ppb_id = PPB.ppb_id
        OR L.ppb_id_2 = PPB.ppb_id)
        AND L.Archived = 0
        FOR XML PATH('')),2,99999)
FROM PPB
WHERE state_code > ''
```

Comment: Legendary! This perfectly solves my problem. Do you happen to have any idea as to why it worked in 2005?

Comment: I am not 100% certain but I believe it's because in 2005 the alias inside the brackets (PPB) was not looking at the PPB table inside the brackets, whereas in 2008 it is.

For example, if you had renamed the table alias outside the brackets to, say, PPBX, and run the same query replacing the PPB.ppb_id in brackets with PPBX.ppb_id, it would have worked.

Comment: e.g. 
    
    Select      PPBX.*,      

    SUBSTRING(STUFF((select license_id as k   --*
    FROM LMACatscan..license AS L 
          WHERE L.archived = 0 
                AND ((L.ppb_id IN (SELECT ppb_id FROM LMACatscan..ppb WHERE ppb_id = PPBX.ppb_id)) 
                OR (L.ppb_id_2 IN (SELECT ppb_id FROM LMACatscan..ppb WHERE ppb_id = PPBX.ppb_id)))
                FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,''),2,999999)    
                FROM   LMACatscan..ppb AS PPBX
                WHERE  state_code > ''

(this would probably also work in 2008, though I haven't tested it)

Comment: In case that was unclear...

SELECT ppb_id FROM LMACatscan..ppb WHERE ppb_id = PPB.ppb_id

2012 thinks "PPB" is referring to the table in this particular select statement (LMACatscan..ppb) because it has the same name as the alias...

2005 is taking "PPB" to mean the PPB alias outside the brackets. 

(also accidentally wrote 2008 instead of 2012 in the previous comments)